# Is this behavior of the Series function correct

Tags: simplifying-expressions, bugs, series-expansion

While series expanding a function, I got an unexpected result, which seems like an error to me. I have boiled it down to this minimum (non) working example:

```
$Assumptions = p \[Element] Reals && x \[Element] Reals;
k = Conjugate[(x^2*(1 + I *p))^2 - x^2*(1 + I*p)];
Expand[FullSimplify[Series[k, {x, 0, 2}]]]
Series[FullSimplify[k], {x, 0, 2}] // TraditionalForm
```

This returns

```
-x^2 + I p x^2 + x^4 - 2 I p x^4 - p^2 x^4
```

and

```
I (p+I) x^2+O(x^3)
```

The second output, where I have first used `FullSimplify` returns the correct output. To my understanding, the first output is wrong. Have I found a bug, or is there something about the `Series` function I don't understand.

Comment: You've just discovered that Conjugate is not a differentiable function.

Comment: Yeah, that might be it. It still seems weird that `FullSimplify` changes whether a expression is differentiable or not. Furthermore, removing either of the `(1 + I p)`-factors results in both outputs being the same. It seems random when the conjugate is considered differentiable or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Series` does not (in this case, anyway) take account of the assumptions.  Since `Conjugate` is not differentiable

```
Series[k, {x, 0, 2}]
```

and

```
k
```

return the same result.

```
FullSimplify[k]
(* (I + p) x^2 (I - (I + p) x^2) *)
```

uses the assumptions and eliminates the `Conjugate` (since the result is valid given the assumptions, and simpler).  Since this simplified form is differentiable (for general values of `x`), `Series` expansion is now possible.

You will find it easier to understand the results, if you consider them one step at a time, rather than chaining them together.

*EDIT*

It is interesting to consider how `Series` accounts for assumptions.  As a quick check on what might be going on, I define

```
$Assumptions = p ∈ Reals && x ∈ Reals;
k = Conjugate[(x^2*(1 + I*p))^2 - x^2*(1 + I*p)];
l = Conjugate[(1 + x)^2];
```

and see the effect that assumptions have with only implict transformations and with `Refine`, `Simplify` and `FullSimplify`

```
{Identity, Refine, Simplify, FullSimplify}[{k, l}] // Through
(* {{Conjugate[-((1 + I p) x^2) + (1 + I p)^2 x^4], (1 + Conjugate[x])^2},
{Conjugate[-((1 + I p) x^2) + (1 + I p)^2 x^4], (1 + x)^2},
{Conjugate[-((1 + I p) x^2) + (1 + I p)^2 x^4], (1 + x)^2},
{(I + p) x^2 (I - (I + p) x^2), (1 + x)^2}} *)
```

From this, it is apparent that `k` requires `FullSimplify` for the assumptions to have an effect, while `l` is simplified with `Refine` alone.  This suggests that `Series` implicitly applies transformations similar to `Refine`.

Comment: That makes sense on its own, but then why is `Series[Conjugate[(1 + x)^2], {x, 0, 1}]` evaluated as a series? It seems arbitrary when Mathematica respects that the conjugate is not differentiable/ considers the assumptions.

Comment: I've edited the question to explain what I think is going on.

Comment: Thank you, that clears up a lot. I come to the conclusion that it is important to run the expression through `FullSimplify` after every time conjugate is used. (Sometimes even twice) Otherwise this can cause a lot of headache.

Comment: If `FullSimplify` works for you, that's good, but it can sometimes take a long time to do very little.  `Refine` is generally very quick and can often be as effective.